# Parent waits for previous child process on linux shell

Tags: c, linux, signals

I have a program that forks a process, and determine if child process should run in foreground and background. I call the signal function to handle the child signal before forking, to make sure dead child process will not turn into zombies.

So far my program works fine, it creates a child process and runs it on background whenever user input commands with '&', and runs it on foreground whenever user input commands without '&'.

However, I found a really interesting behaviour. Suppposed I called this sequence of operations:

```
sleep 5 &
ls
```

the first command will work fine, parent process does not wait for sleep 5 to finish. However, when I run "ls", it prints all the files in that folder (which is good) but then the shell is stuck, waiting for previous "sleep 5 &" to finish...

Why does this occur? My code for child and parent process (after forking) looks pretty much like below:

```
 if (pid == 0)
 {
      // child process, execute stuff
      execv();
 } 
 else if (pid > 0) 
 {
      // parent process: call waitpid to wait for foreground child
 }
```

I tried to do some research, but I can't find anything that can help me. I tried using "set session-id" for child process, by calling it before the execv(), but it prevents my child process to print anything on terminal.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There are many possibilities.  Without seeing more code, it's tough to guess at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>

    void run_command(void)
    {
        char *cmd = NULL, *arg;
        size_t n, l;
        bool background;
        pid_t child;

        l = getline(&cmd, &n, stdin);
        cmd[l-1] = 0;
        l--;

        if (cmd[l-1] == '&') {
            background = true;
            cmd[l-1] = 0;
            l--;
        }
        else
            background = false;

        arg = strchr(cmd, ' ');
        if (arg) {
            *arg = 0;
            arg++;
        }

        child = fork();

        if (child) {
            if (!background)
                waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
        }
        else {
            execlp(cmd, cmd, arg, NULL);
            exit(-1);
        }

        free(cmd);
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        sigset_t set;
        struct sigaction sig;

        sigemptyset(&set);
        sig.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
        sig.sa_mask = set;
        sig.sa_flags = SA_NOCLDWAIT;
        sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sig, NULL);

        while(!feof(stdin)) run_command();
    }
```

This works as expected:

```
hdante@aielwaste:~/code$ ./shell 
pwd
/home/hdante/code
ls /home
hdante
sleep 5
ls /
bin    dev   initrd.img      lib32   lost+found  opt   run      srv  usr      vmlinuz.old
boot   etc   initrd.img.old  lib64   media       proc  sbin     sys  var
cdrom  home  lib         libnss3.so  mnt         root  selinux  tmp  vmlinuz
sleep 5&
xedit&
ls /
bin    dev   initrd.img      lib32   lost+found  opt   run      srv  usr      vmlinuz.old
boot   etc   initrd.img.old  lib64   media       proc  sbin     sys  var
cdrom  home  lib         libnss3.so  mnt         root  selinux  tmp  vmlinuz
```

In the example above, sleep 5 correctly blocks, while sleep 5& and xedit& don't.

Without looking at your code, it's impossible to know where's the problem. Notice however the way I'm handling zombie process: I use SA_NOCLDWAIT in sa_flags, so that I don't need to track pids. Also, I wait for the foreground child process using waitpid(). And that's where I think the problem is. It's probable that your code is calling wait() instead of waitpid(). The difference is that wait() waits for all children.